# Multiple Websites not working on Nginx Revrese Proxy

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

One of the website is not accessible via nginx reverse proxy when we have configuration files of two different websites (hosted on two docker containers) palced under /etc/nginx/conf.d. The configuration files are as follows

Website 1: /etc/nginx/conf.d/tr.conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tr.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tr.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    server_name trac.internal.local;
    location /trend {
        proxy_pass http://tr/trend:9090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect http://tr/trend /;
    }
}
```

Website 2: /etc/nginx/conf.d/pageview.conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/pageview.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/pageview.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    server_name pageview.internal.local;
    location /pageview {
        proxy_pass http://pageviewfront:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect http://pageviewfront /;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Not accessible"* and *"not working"* are error descriptions which don't really help. What exact error messages you get or what exactly is behaving contrary to what expectation on how it should work? What information you get from the server error log files?

Comment: when try to access https://nginx-ip/pageview, the webpage loading as expected. However, getting 404 Not Found error when accessing https://nignx-ip/trend.

After changing port to 9443 on second website, issue fixed, seems like issue with port. however, wanted to run both websites on 443 only.
Using port 443 for both websites is the issue

Comment: Why do you use nginx-ip? The configured sites have a domain name and the config is applied only if the proper domain name is used in the URL. Using nginx-ip will either fail or will simply use one of the configurations as fallback but never use the other.

Comment: Here, we are trying to achieve https connections to backend HTTP web servers using nginx reverse proxy, So, same nginx container will be used for multiple http web applications running on containers.

Comment: See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_name for how to pass the name from nginx reverse proxy to the backend so that the right nginx configuration is used.